# Matrix type 90s cartoon where a bald man is transported into another world

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember a bald man. The overall setting was green and dark, it was like they got transported to another world just like in the movie *Matrix*. Searched everywhere but all in vain. And some sound like "Standby". It was pronounced like this or it was the exact word. The main character wore glasses and got into another world.

It was like a computer based world. No alternate dimension, Not Anime, simple 2d cartoons as they were back in the day. The main character was bald and wore glasses something like the laser guy in X-Men, who shoots laser through his eyes, but they were green.

Comment: Was it a computer-based world? An alternate dimension? Western cartoon? Anime? Was the main character the bald man or was he someone secondary? Were the glasses like reading glasses? Sunglasses? Goggles? A visor?

Comment: If you go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info, we have some prompts to elicit more info. Please go through those and see if you can think of anything else.